# Getting output of command execution on windowed app

Tags: python, output, popen, windowed

I have created a Python script and compiled it into an exe file with PyInstaller. In the process, I have specified the -w option to get an app that doesn't have any console.

Everything works fine except the execution of commands using popen:

```
mout = subprocess.Popen(['ls','C:\'])
```

This line generates an exception `[Error 6] The handle is invalid`.

I have tried adding the parameters 
`stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE` but it stills not working. I think that is because the main process doesn't have any console assigned. I want to execute the command but without opening any shell, it has to be transparent to the user.

Is there any option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your issue.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls','C:\\'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

Comment: If I add the _shell=True_ the Popen works fine but a CMD appears for a moment on the screen. I want to avoid showing shells on the execution of the command.

Comment: I have added an extra option and it doesn't show the shell so it works perfec: _creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW_.